# dell inspiron 6000 laptop will not come on notthing will come on

Tags: windows-7

How to turn my dell laptop back on nothing will come on even the screen won't come on  I have try every thing on YouTube has tell me to so please help me

Answer (score -2):

The following is based on my experience selling laptops for the past 5 years:

- no power

  - plug directly into a power outlet
  - if there is still no power,
    use a different power outlet
  - if there is still no power, then use another charger or power adapter
- has power but blank screen

  - rule out an LCD or screen issue by connecting the laptop to an external monitor using a VGA or HDMI cable
  - if that doesn't work, replace your RAM
  - if that doesn't work, check your video card as this issue is common with faulty video cards, especially integrated video cards from Nvidia and ATI